# Getting strange output of below code. I need explaination how it wil calculate output

Tags: php

```
<?php
$test = 'text1';
$test["02"] = "Hello";

var_dump($test);
```

Output is::
string(5) "teHt1"

Comment: Turn on error display, you'll get "_Warning: Only the first byte will be assigned to the string offset in ..._". What did you expect as outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in the first line $test stored the value as 'text1'
start giving offset value for the string from left to right from 0 to (stringlength-1) and each character byte size in string will occupies one byte of memory.

ie,

...

```
$test[0] =>'t';
$test[1] =>'e';
$test[2]=>'x';
$test[3]=>'t';
$test[4]=> '1';
```

...

so, $test[2] current value as 'x' but we are tried to override in the line $test["02"] = "Hello";
but its memory size just one byte so it stored only 'H' from the string in 'Hello'

that's why when you dump the variable $test value is now **"teHt1"**;

Answer (score 0):

Strings are not arrays even you can use bracket notation.you are trying to replace second byte offset of the $test variable.So it takes the first byte offset from "Hello" and replaces x with H.